# PHP: updating product table quantity while fetching data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue on updating the fetched data from invoiceitem table to update the product table `quantity`.

**This issue is only the first record is updating** on my loop.

Please help me on updating multiple item values to the DB.

Here is my code:

```
<?php



$stuid = $_GET['id'];
global $con;

                    $stu_query = "SELECT * FROM invoiceorder INNER JOIN invoiceorderitem ON invoiceorder.InvoId = invoiceorderitem.InvoId WHERE invoiceorder.InvoId ='$stuid'";

                    $stu_run = mysqli_query($con,$stu_query);


                    while($sorows = mysqli_fetch_array($stu_run)){
                        $Date = $sorows['Date'];
                        $SalesPerson = $sorows['SalesPerson'];
                        $Telephone = $sorows['Telephone'];                              
                        $Customer = $sorows['Customer'];                                
                        $CurrentPayment = $sorows['CurrentPayment'];                                
                        $Balance = $sorows['Balance'];                              

                        $Item_Id = $sorows['Item_Id'];
                        $ItemDescription = $sorows['ItemDescription'];
                        $UnitPrice = $sorows['UnitPrice'];
                        $Quantity = $sorows['Quantity'];
                        $SubTotal = $sorows['SubTotal'];
                        $Total = $sorows['Total'];

                     $sea_res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bincard WHERE BinId = $Item_Id");

                                        while ($resresults = $sea_res->fetch_assoc()){

                                            $BinId = $resresults['BinId'];
                                            $ItemName = $resresults['ItemName'];
                                            $QtyBalance = $resresults['QtyBalance'];
                                            $QtyIssued = $resresults['QtyIssued'];

                                            //chech this
                                            $newqty=0;
                                            $isuqty=0;

                                            $newqty =$QtyBalance - $Quantity;
                                            $isuqty = $QtyIssued + $Quantity;
                                            $insert_query = "UPDATE bincard SET QtyBalance='$newqty',QtyIssued='$isuqty' WHERE BinId = $Item_Id";
                                        }
                                        if ($con->query($insert_query) === TRUE) 
                        {
                            echo"<script>alert(' Updated Successfully')</script>";
                            echo"<script>window.open('invoiceprint.php','_self')</script>";
                        } else 
                        {
                            echo "Error: " . $insert_query . "<br>" . $con->error;
                        }



                        $con->close();
                    }







?>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow. This is just a friendly reminder that your code is vulnerable to MySQL injection. You should consider using [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as this code is not suitable for production

Comment: Your code is failing because your `if ($con->query($insert_query) === TRUE)` sits outside of the while loop. Move the if statment block within your while loop and it'll insert the full array.

Comment: `This issue is only the first record is updating` is actually incorrect; it's actually only updating the last record. Just nit picking =)

Comment: @IsThisJavascript nope..! only the first record is been updating other data skips..thanking you

Comment: Hmm, you could double check this by running `print_r($sea_res)`. `$insert_query` is getting set during every loop and it's only after the loop is finished that you are running your SQL query command.. hence last piece of data is updating not the first. As the first was overwritten long ago... But that's not the point of the question anyway. Hope you managed to solve your issue.

Comment: well thank you... i'll double check on it bro.hope i'll get good answer for my issue on updating. thank you again for giving ur time on this.

Comment: No problem hasan, but I have already given you the solution to your problem in my second comment. Just move your full code block that starts with `if ($con->query($insert_query) === TRUE)`  inside the `while` loop and your issue will be resolved..

Comment: i tried adding this " if ($con->query($insert_query) === TRUE)" into my while loop but still only one record getting updated in the bincard table quantity field where my other records still doesn't update..issue is still there.

Comment: Did you include the `echo "Error: " . $insert_query . "<br>" . $con->error;`? You must get an output if you're still only getting 1 update? Are you sure `$sea_res->fetch_assoc()` has even more than 1 result?

Comment: yes i have include  echo ` "Error: " . $insert_query . "<br>" . $con->error;? ` ..yes there are multiple results on  $sea_res->fetch_assoc() because first while loop fetches more than 1 result on `$item_id` ..so based on that `$item_id` in bincard the matching records are been fetched to update. please advice me whether my loops are correct.  thankyou

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `if ($con->query($insert_query) === TRUE)` inside the `while` loop. if it's only updating one record then `$sea_res->fetch_assoc()` has only 1 record in it.

```
while ($resresults = $sea_res->fetch_assoc()){

    $BinId = $resresults['BinId'];
    $ItemName = $resresults['ItemName'];
    $QtyBalance = $resresults['QtyBalance'];
    $QtyIssued = $resresults['QtyIssued'];

    //chech this
    $newqty=0;
    $isuqty=0;

    $newqty =$QtyBalance - $Quantity;
    $isuqty = $QtyIssued + $Quantity;
    $insert_query = "UPDATE bincard SET QtyBalance='$newqty',QtyIssued='$isuqty' WHERE BinId = $Item_Id";

    if ($con->query($insert_query) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo"<script>alert(' Updated Successfully')</script>";
        echo"<script>window.open('invoiceprint.php','_self')</script>";
    } else{
        echo "Error: " . $insert_query . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: if so as you said it only updates one record where last saved `$item_id` variable is only fetching 1 value.... then the issue should be in my first while loop and the variable which doesn't keep multiple data  ..please would you check my first while loop . thanking for being with me